# Accessing JavaScript variables inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to use a variable to hold an HTML id so I don't have to keep writing `getElementById` over and over again.  But I can't get this to work.  Here's my code:

```
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');

function slide4(){
    box1.style.width='10%';
}
```

It works if I put the variable inside the function, but that seems like bad practice as I want to access that variable in other functions and don't want to keep declaring the variable over and over again.

```
function slide4(){
    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
    box1.style.width='10%';
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You say you can't get this to work. What actually happens when you try it?

Comment: must be scoping issues. Try declaring the variable without the var keyword and see if it works

Comment: Can you post all your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you access the DOM before it has been loaded. Try this instead:

```
var box1;

window.onload = function() {
    box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
}

function slide4() {
    box1.style.width = '10%';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the **box1** initialization is run after the page gets loaded.
So one solution would be this:

```
var box1 = null;
window.onload = function(){
    box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
}
```

Another solution is to create a function, instead of that variable, and use it whenever you want:

```
function BoxID(){
    return document.getElementById('box1');
}
```

Of course, if you use jquery library, whenever you want you can use:

```
$("#box1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to pass variable as argument:

```
var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');

function slide4(box){
    box.style.width='10%';
}
```

Also you can define variable without `var` that will make it property of `window` object

```
box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
alert(window.box1);
```